# Spotlight Search API iOS9

Tags: ios9, corespotlight

I wonder which property of CSSearchableItemAttributeSet is responsible for displaying kind of subtitle, located just on the right of title for example with a date.

Answer (score 3):

When you set the attributeSet's contentType property to kUTTypeMessage, then the contentCreationDate is what you are looking for.

```
set.contentType = (NSString *)kUTTypeMessage;
set.contentCreationDate = [NSDate date];
```

Try it~
BTW, god damn Apple Document...